# Which is a good free software for full website downloading and viewing offline?

Tags: windows, download, website

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Website downloader (cache?) to view sites offline](https://superuser.com/questions/214444/website-downloader-cache-to-view-sites-offline)

I have been using Meta Products Offline Explorer in the past.

Has anyone got good recommendations on some free alternatives, preferably which can run portably on multiple computers.

Comment: You could try wget -r www.blah.com that would probably work, though would likely be big.   I sometimes download a webpage and its links, wget -r -l 1 www.blah.com/whateverpage.html

Comment: I would like some advanced configurations like not to download from other servers or domains. Or to skip certain file extensions such as .js or images. Can I do that in wget ?

Comment: I think that in HTTrack you can do that filtering, at least extension filtering is available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTrack is one of the alternatives. http://www.httrack.com/

Answer (score 4):

Wget for windows is another alternative. It has the advantage of being run at command line

```
wget -r -l [depth] [site]
```

e.g.

```
wget -r -l 5 http://foo.com/bar.html
```

will download all links down to 5th level
use the `-m` if you want to do a mirror of the site concerned.

Wget for windows is available at http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Comment: -m flag = Turn on options suitable for mirroring. This option turns on recursion and time-stamping, sets infinite recursion depth and keeps FTP directory listings. It is currently equivalent to -r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing. (from manpage)

Comment: I usually use something like `wget -e robots=off -r -nc --no-parent http://foo/bar/`.  You need to ignore robots.txt if you want to get all the parts of the site that are not indexed by search engines.

Comment: You probably also want `--convert-links` (convert links so that they work locally, e.g. change /title.gif to ../title.gif, remove http etc.). Otherwise most links inside the documents most likely won't work, so you cannot browse them offline. Also `--page-requisites ` (download images,CSS etc. along with every HTML page).