# Make chrome webpages available offline

Tags: google-chrome, browser, web

I'm travelling today and want to do some work on the plane/train etc. I won't have access to the internet but there's a few web pages I'd like to have available for reference.

Is there anyway to make pages available offline in chrome? I realise I can pin a page, but this leaves the door open for accidentally closing the tab or hitting refresh etc.

Ideally I'd like an extension which did something like: right click on tab, select "Make available offline" and then if I'm not connected to the internet and go to that page then it's loaded from cache.

Any ideas?

Comment: A related question: http://superuser.com/questions/459196/is-it-possible-to-work-offline-in-google-chrome-as-in-firefox

Answer (score 12):

Some Chrome extensions I know of:

### [Scrapbook](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fihabipakbgncingdhhdidlbhneeicne)

> Scrapbook merges all the fragmented features in various scrapbook
>   implementations into one.
>
> Some extensions don't annotate but save offline, some save but need
>   you to register on another social network. Some save images(which I
>   actually prefer). But cant be indexed and searched. My Scrapbook is an
>   attempt to do all that. In short it aspires to be like my favourite
>   [Firefox counter part](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/427/).

### [Chromium Scrapbook](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gokffdfnlmampchciemmflgbckijpmlb)

> Save web pages for offline use.
>
> This extension allows to save web pages for later use without internet
>   connection. It tries to save complete markup and graphics, so saved
>   page looks the same as online one. The stored pages can be organized
>   using tags. Text descriptions can be added to saved pages.

### [Pocket (formerly Read It Later)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/niloccemoadcdkdjlinkgdfekeahmflj)

> Pocket Extension for Google Chrome – The best way to save articles,
>   videos and more
>
> When you find something on the web that you want to view later, put it
>   in Pocket. It automatically syncs to your phone, tablet or computer so
>   you can view it at any time, even without an internet connection.
>
> Extension Features:
>   * One-click saving of any page with the toolbar button or keyboard shortcut
>   * Integrated buttons on Twitter.com and Google Reader for one-click saving
>   * Right-click menu item to save any link, no need to load the page first
>   * Quickly add tags
>   * Syncs across all devices – iPhone, iPad, Android and more
>   * Completely free

[*Similar extensions, but for Firefox.*](https://superuser.com/a/214489/10259)

Comment: Are there any extensions that automatically update the cached pages?

Comment: Read later fast seems to be removed.

Comment: @PieterDeBie Thanks for mentioning that. I've removed the link to 'Read later fast' in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

There seems to be a new "use stale copy" mode in future chrome versions: https://plus.google.com/+FrancoisBeaufort/posts/5cgwTEmqAvC

> In cases in which a network error occurs and that Chrome has a stale copy of the resource that is attempting to be loaded, a "Load Stale Local Copy" button is shown on the network error page in the last chromium build.
>
> Source: https://codereview.chromium.org/207553008
>
> [image]

There is also chrome://flags/#show-saved-copy

Comment: http://addyosmani.com/blog/offline-mode-chrome/

Comment: This is available at chrome://flags/#show-saved-copy - it is called "Show Saved Copy Button", as of June 2016, and it works wonderfully!

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do this in Chrome. First, you can right click in a blank space on the page and select "Save As". Second, you can click the wrench icon in the top right and select "Save Page As". Both of these will allow you to choose the name and location to save the page as a .htm file. In the dropdown below the filename, you can choose either "Webpage, Complete" or "Webpage, HTML only". HTML Only will save an htm file of the page, but the resource links will remain pointing to the website. Complete will save the html page as well as all page resources, and change the links in the html to point to the resources folder.

You might also take a look at [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/), if you are interested in making entire websites available offline.

Hm, this [Read Later First](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/decdfngdidijkdjgbknlnepdljfaepji?hl=en-US) plugin might be what you're looking for. It adds an entry to the context menu: "Read Later". I'm not sure if it lets you just type in the address to view it, but it sounds like it would be easier than saving the html on your computer. It also appears to have an online sync feature, so you could save a page on one device, and read it later on another.

Comment: I should have specified, I am aware I can do save as, but as this often doesn't capture all related resources, js, images, etc. I was hoping for something more integrated, something that would allow the pages to be reproduced exactly and also something that would allow to just type the address into the browser.

Comment: Saving as "Webpage, Complete" will save all images and js. I'm still looking, but I haven't found any way to just type the address in and get the offline version.

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed that option.

Comment: I've added a couple more options I found.

Comment: Read Later First looks very good, was just about to install it when I saw this 'also integrates "Price Comparison While You Shop"'

Comment: Yeah, I saw that :( Not sure if there's any way to disable it or not. I wouldn't be surprised if you could do so through the plugin's settings.

Comment: @SaintWacko When saving a complete webpage, where will the resources be saved? I wonder if it's practical, and if it can be used for any webpage.

Comment: It saves the resources in a folder alongside the html file.

Answer (score 1):

You can save it as MHTML file by using "SAVE AS MHTML" extension available in chrome web store which will capture the entire site to a compressed file.

Supported by Firefox, Internet Explorer and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

No extension required:

This is available at `chrome://flags/#show-saved-copy`

As of June 2016, it is now called the "Show Saved Copy Button"

And it works wonderfully!

---

Huge thanks to https://superuser.com/a/769012/354941 for linking the blog post to the (now outdated) forefather to the "Show Saved Copy Button"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Chrome, but these instructions are for saving in IE but viewing in Chrome  (simply because I don't have Chrome in front of me). However, it does exactly what you need.

I would suggest you save the complete page (in the drop down box - see picture below). This means you have a local copy and can open it in Chrome. I don't have Chrome here so I can't test it in Chrome, but the screen shot I show is done in IE.

Please note, complete includes images, css files, javascript files etc.

This also bypasses the issue of if you close the tab or not as it's physically on your machine.

[image]

Comment: Chrome doesn't have a File menu.

Comment: I know, I hit 'post answer' without making it clear I was talking about IE.