# Cache web pages in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make chrome webpages available offline](https://superuser.com/questions/470813/make-chrome-webpages-available-offline)

Is there a chrome extension that will allow me cache a web page so that I can access it later on without the internet?

Comment: Isn't right click -> "save as" enough?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about **Google Chrome**, but **Opera** will be of interest to you here. It uses Presto as the rendering engine and the webpages you open in Opera can be accessed even after you've disconnected from the web (the next and back buttons work as if you're still connected to the web). It doesn't work for HTTPS-enabled sites of course.